# Armature object disappears when rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, armature

Everything is visible in the render viewport, but when I render the image my model disappears. I saw that this can happen when an armature is parented to it, but I dont know how to fix it. Feels like Ive tried everything.

Heres the blend file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj9044td6viq7z6/RoyalSkiesLLC-RoyalRig-Female2.9.blend1?dl=0
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: please show us what you have (viewport) and your rendered result as screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Don't know how to solve (I think it's a bug), but I can tell you that the problem is not about rendering, it's about animation: The mesh gets rendered, but in a weird loc and deformation. I think this is due to a wrong evaluation of its path constraint, which is ok in viewport, but it's not ok in render. I've found this problem before, in constraints and modifiers applied to Grease Pencil objects. To pratically solve you should try to get rid of that path constraint, or use the simple viewport render. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice, for some reason I just moved the rigged model into a collection unrelated to the armature and it seemed to have worked. No idea why. I appreciate the support!!